# Удаление экзепляров QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, память

Надо ли удалять экзепляры QGraphicsItem обычным оператором `delete` из C++ (чтобы освободить память), если они уже были удалены со сцены методом `QGraphicsScene::removeItem(QGraphicsItem * item)` или это сделается автоматически?

Comment: Кстати, если вы удалите итем при помощи `delete`, он автоматически удалится из сцены. Так что можно не вызывать `removeItem`, а сразу удалять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [справке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem):

> Removes the item item and all its children from the scene. The
>   ownership of item is passed on to the caller (i.e., QGraphicsScene
>   will no longer delete item when destroyed).

..., что можно перевести, как - да, придётся удалять собственными силами. На мой взгляд, неудачное имя подобрано методу, поскольку во всех аналогичных случаях в Qt обычно используется слово `take`.

Comment: А с методом void QGraphicsScene::clear() так же?

Comment: @havon, там полное удаление, как положено: "removes and deletes all items from the scene".